# lifecycle hook in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lifecycle

I've made child component like this.
and,
In the hooks, the props is a "previous one".

Any advice for me?

```
// Parent
const [state, setState] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
  emitter.on('EVENT', (o) => {
    setState(o); // when the 'EVENT' fired, update state.
  });
}, []);

<Child code={state.code} />
```

```
interface childProps = {
  code;
}
const Child: React.FC = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log(props.code); // <= Q. props value is previous one.
    };
  }, [props.code]);

  return (
    <div>{props.code}</div> // Here is okay. current props value.
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    // current props value.
    return () => {
      // previous props value
    };
  }, [props.code]);
```

;(